# View grails domain class property in another domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Hi I am just trying out grails and trying to learn more on domain class. I have two simple domain classes:

**Domain Class 1**

```
package grailtest

class Person {

    String  firstName
    String  lastName
    int age
    String  email

    static constraints = {
    }

}
```

**Domain Class 2**

```
package grailtest

class Customer {

    String  customerId
    Person  personInCharge

    static constraints = {
    }

}
```

When I do a run-app, I can only see

grailtest.Person : 1

as the Person. How can I default it to a particular value, for instance firstName + lastName, to make the application more user friendly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the domain override toString method to what you wanted to be display. restart the app

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`@ToString`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/ToString.html) in case you want an elaborative way of logging or printing in standard out.

```
import groovy.transform.ToString

@ToString(includeNames=true, includeFields=true)
class Person {
    String  firstName
    String  lastName
    int age
    String  email
}
```

For example,

```
def person = new Person(firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'hola', 
                          age: 10, email: 'abc@xyz.com')
```

would give

```
Person(firstName:Test, lastName:hola, age:10, email:abc@xyz.com)
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the view where it displays **grailstest.Person: 1** and update it to:

```
${personInstance.firstName} ${personInstance.lastName}
```

By default this view should be in *"views/person"*

Answer (score 1):

You put this code in the view .gsp

```
${personInstance?.firstname} ${personInstance?.lastname}
```